# When to not use useMemo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-usememo

I am using `useMemo` to much in my `Functional Components`, and I am worry about it which will it be a good experience to use it to much in our App?

**Why I am using it to much?**

I have a to much `Components` which they dont need to be re-rendered except in special circumstances, and this is why I am avoiding them from re-rendering.

**Code:**

```
const App = props => {


 const Comp1 = useMemo(()=> <Component1 {...props} a={a} />, [a]);
 const Comp2 = useMemo(()=> <Component2 {...props} b={b} />, [b]);
 const Comp3 = useMemo(()=> <Component3 {...props} c={c} />, [c]);
 const Comp4 = useMemo(()=> <Component4 {...props} d={d} />, [d]);
 const Comp5 = useMemo(()=> <Component5 {...props} e={e} />, [e]);
 const Comp6 = useMemo(()=> <Component6 {...props} f={f} />, [f]);
 const Comp7 = useMemo(()=> <Component7 {...props} g={g} />, [g]);
 const Comp8 = useMemo(()=> <Component8 {...props} h={h} />, [h]);
 const Comp9 = useMemo(()=> <Component9 {...props} i={i} />, [i]);

 return (
   <View>
     {Comp1}
     {Comp2}
     {Comp3}
     {Comp4}
     {Comp5}
     {Comp6}
     {Comp7}
     {Comp8}
     {Comp9}
   </View>
 );
}
```

There may I have more than 20 `Functional Components`, and in all them I have the same situations as I am using to much `useMemo` hooks.

My Question is is this a `bad experience` which affect bad `performance` instead of good `performance`? or not there is no problem per my conditions.

Comment: That's what called [premature optimization](https://www.google.com/search?q=premature+optimization+is+the+root+of+all+evil&oq=premature+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i59l2j0l5.3006j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Do you have a **specific** performance issue that you measured? If so, you should consider this specifics and not optimize everything without care.

Comment: Honestly, I would say that if you are rarely rendering them then that is a reason to not memoize them unless they are expensive to render and will re-render often once rendered.  If you know a component is going to be re-rendered all the time and/or is expensive to render then consider the use of useMemo.

Comment: @DennisVash thank you, yeah I measured, some of components with using `useMemo` is working well and feel that as there is, prevented from unnecessary rendering, but sometime in some component I am watching more 'dropped so far' in `profiler` while using `useMemo`.

Comment: @terpinmd thank you, Can a functional component be expensive with a list of 30 items, should I avoid its unnecessary rendering by using `useMemo`?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the same general advice applies for React.memo as it does for shouldComponentUpdate and PureComponent: doing comparisons does have a small cost, and there's scenarios where a component would never memoize properly (especially if it makes use of props.children). So, don't just automatically wrap everything everywhere. See how your app behaves in production mode, use React's profiling builds and the DevTools profiler to see where bottlenecks are, and strategically use these tools to optimize parts of the component tree that will actually benefit from these optimizations.

Comment: Could you please, suggest me, which is better `memo()` or `useMemo` ?